# Outbound Emails flagged as Spam from Wordpress but not Gmail(DKIM SPF issues)

Tags: email, spam, spf, dkim

I recently setup wordpress and pointed my domain to it.  With that, we setup gsuite to handle email.  We have the domain at godaddy and the server space on a VPS instance.  I have added the MX records as google suggested at the domain level in godaddy and confirmed with them that it is working(I was able to send and receive emails from a domain level address). When sending from gmail, there is no issue.  However, when sending from wordpress(whether its resending the admin email, using a plugin, or testing woocommerce) the email always gets flagged with an error message like the following:

This message has a from an address in mydomain.com but has failed mydomain.com's required tests for authentication.

Upon looking at the details of the email, I can see there are SPF and DKIM issues:

SPF:    NEUTRAL with IP 66.85.47.192 Learn more
DKIM:   'FAIL' with domain mydomain.com Learn more

```
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       dkim=temperror (no key for signature) header.i=@mydomain.com header.s=default header.b=nEQZ9ib3;
       spf=neutral (google.com: 662.835.457.12 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of mydomain@server2.server.com) smtp.mailfrom=mydomain@server2.server.com
```

I am completely lost and no one at either godaddy, google or my hosting has been able to figure it out. I am almost positive the issue is on the hosting environment because It doesnt get flagged when being sent from Gmail.  Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: What sort of help are you looking for? You haven't provided any relevant information beyond the error messages. Please add all relevant information to your question, and [include the real domain name](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/126632) if possible.

Comment: Easy, sign your emails with dkim on the vps

Comment: A possible clue can be found in server2.server.com as the sending domain. Did you set up SPF and DKIM for server2.server.com?

The domain actually sending the email server2.server.com (the return path) cn be different than the friendly from address that you see in the "from:"

Comment: Please post what you have for SPF, DKIM, for your root domain, and for server2.server.com. Then what emails are you sending from the root domain and which are you sending from server2.server.com? They need to be authenticated as such.